# Android TextView as Password broke on Lollipop

Tags: android, textview, passwords, android-5.0-lollipop

We use the following piece of code to change a TextView to hide the text for a password entry box.  On Android Lollipop, this causes the entry box to become not editable, although it can be selected.

```
if (isPassword) {
    setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
    setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
}
```

How to fix this so it works on Android 2.3.5 through Lollipop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this same problem and fixed it by removing use of setInputType.  However this can allow text suggestions to still be shown as noted in the comments.  By changing setInputType to setRawInputType it appears that it will work on both Android 5.0 Lollipop as well as suppress text suggestions.

```
setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

I consider this somewhat of a kludge since setTransformationMethod seems to take care of things by itself except on a few versions of android.

Comment: This seems to work, except on a Samsung tablet w/ Android 4.4.2, it displays the predictive suggestions which means the entire password is displayed in plain text in the keyboard.

Comment: I updated the answer to include use of setRawInputType which appears to suppress the text suggestions without locking things up on Android 5.0 Lollipop.